# How to auto adjust cell height in fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, cell, fpdf

How can I auto adjust the cell height in fpdf?

My pdf looks a little bit bad ;)

[Screenshot of PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzdPt.png)

My code:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 13);
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(30);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(193,229,252);
    $pdf->Cell(15, 20, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[0], 10, 'Datum', 1, 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[1], 10, 'Von', 1, 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[2], 10, 'Bis', 1, 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[3], 10, 'Grund', 1, 1, 'C', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 13);
    $fill = false;
    while ($z = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],10,date("d.m.Y", strtotime($z['date'])),1,0,'C',$fill);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],10,substr($z['startTime'], 0, 5) . ' Uhr',1,0,'C',$fill);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],10,substr($z['endTime'], 0, 5) . ' Uhr',1,0,'C',$fill);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],10,$z['reason'],1,1,'C',$fill);

    }
    $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: You can use the script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3).

Answer (score 0):

To output multiple lines into a cell you'll need to use [MultiCell](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rfpdf/1.17.4/TCPDF:MultiCell) instead of Cell.